# Class D Amp headphones grounding circuit

Tags: amplifier, analog, pwm

[image]I am having a problem with some of the class d amps I've played with (PAM8302A), and it seems like this article here describes my problem:
https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4313726/Add-headphones-to-a-Class-D-amplifier
essentially the audio circuit turns off because of the headphone plug sharing a common ground or something. I am making a pi zero pwm to analog amplifier circuit and some suggestions would be appreciated.[image: PAM8302A]

Edit: How is this? 220uF cap highlighted

Comment: There is a short circuit through C3. I can see a net / trace going through it. Don't base your PCB design on this.

Comment: I just did that to mock up a capacitor in that location, I just now redid the two traces in and out of the capacitor.

Comment: what's the point of using a class D amp for headphones? class D is typically used for efficiency, but that is generally not that big a deal for headphones - unless you are making a portable music player or something.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a 470uF capacitor into the VO_P output with the capacitor + lead going to the IC. Now you are no longer shorting out the DC bias voltage at the output pins. Use small cell-phone type headphones or earbuds to get enough volume. You need 2 of these ICs for stereo sound. This IC cannot drive studio grade headphones, at least not to any useful volume.

Comment: Do you suppose I could add 4 x 100 uF caps and 1 x 70uF all in parallel? I have some major clearance issues and 470uF is the limit of surface mounted ceramic capacitors, with the max voltage that I found of 4V and 10$ a pop.

Comment: That is tough because that value is normally aluminum can type electrolytics. You can vertically stack SMD capacitors to get a higher value. Also small headphones and earbuds tend to be 32 ohms, so you get bass with less capacitance. I would stack the highest SMD value possible. Even 200uF should be ok.

Comment: Please check out the edit I made above.

Comment: That is correct and should work fine. Remember you cannot use VO_N of either channel.

Comment: The capacitance is determined by the headphones impedance that you did not tell us. 600 ohms per ear headphones use 15uF coupling capacitors for -3dB at 17Hz.  If your headphones are 32 ohms per ear then use 220uF.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not caused by "class-D". Instead your problem is caused by the bridged amplifiers for each channel that have a live signal for each of the two speaker wires with no ground. Your headphones use one signal wire and ground for each channel.

For each amplifier channel, connect amplifier V0_P through a coupling capacitor to one earphone wire and connect the other earphone wire to signal ground. Then do the same for the other earphone.